# How to add image using getResource() in NetBeans in a Maven project

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to add images using this code in NetBeans but the image is not getting added 
I have used multiple ways by adding '/' in front of res but it is still not working

This is the file structure

```
--src
  -res(inside src folder)
    -imgglug(inside res folder)
      -blue.png(inside imgglug folder)
      -no2.png
       ..(more png images are stored in imgglug folder)
```

---

```
private void loadNumberTiles()
{
  numberTiles=new Hashtable();
 
  ClassLoader cldr=this.getClass().getClassLoader();
 java.net.URL url0000=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/blue.png");
 java.net.URL url0002=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no2.png");
 java.net.URL url0004=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no4.png");
 java.net.URL url0008=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no8.png");
 java.net.URL url0016=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no16.png");
 java.net.URL url0032=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no32.png");
 java.net.URL url0064=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no64.png");
 java.net.URL url0128=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no128.png");
 java.net.URL url0256=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no256.png");
 java.net.URL url0512=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no.512.png");
 java.net.URL url1024=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no.1024.png");
 java.net.URL url2048=cldr.getResource("res/imgglug/no.2048.png");
 if(url0000!=null)
     {
         numberTiles.put(0,new ImageIcon(url0000));
     }
     if(url0002!=null)
             {
                numberTiles.put(2,new ImageIcon(url0002)); 
             }
     if(url0004!=null)
             {
                numberTiles.put(4,new ImageIcon(url0004)); 
             }
     if(url0008!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(8,new ImageIcon(url0008));
             }
     if(url0016!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(16,new ImageIcon(url0016));
             }
     if(url0032!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(32,new ImageIcon(url0032));
             }
     if(url0064!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(64,new ImageIcon(url0064));
             }
     if(url0128!=null)
             {
                  numberTiles.put(128,new ImageIcon(url0128));
             }
     if(url0256!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(256,new ImageIcon(url0256));
             }
     if(url0512!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(512,new ImageIcon(url0512));
             }
     
     if(url1024!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(1024,new ImageIcon(url1024));
             }
     if(url2048!=null)
             {
                 numberTiles.put(2048,new ImageIcon(url2048));
             } }
```

Comment: Is the res folder built into the jar?

Comment: /src/main/resources/ is where you need to keep resources if you want them to be loadable and address them beginning '/'